# Saving data from Arduino using Python - loss of data

Tags: python, pandas, arduino

With the help of web, i have created a code that collects the data form Arduino uno, and saves it to csv file. 
The data collected are raw values of MEMS accelerometers.

The problem in code is that very often i loose a lot of data, if not all, if i terminate the Python. I noticed that at a random time, the output csv file has zero bytes. 
Temporary  solution is to start Arduino's "Serial monitor". This way most of the measured data is saved.

```
import serial
import time
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

timeHr = []
timeT = []
mem1xD = []
mem1yD = []
mem1zD = []
#
mem2xD = []
mem2yD = []
mem2zD = []


arduinoData = serial.Serial('COM4',9600)


df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'timeHr':0,
                    'timeT':0,
                    'mem1xD':0,
                    'mem1yD':0,
                    'mem1zD':0,
                    'mem2xD':0,
                    'mem2yD':0,
                    'mem2zD':0,
                   }, 
                  index=[0]
                  )

while True:
    while (arduinoData.inWaiting()==0):
        pass
    arduinoString = arduinoData.readline().decode("utf-8")

    dataArray = arduinoString.split(",")

    timehr = dataArray[0]
    time = float(dataArray[1])/1000

    mem1x = float(dataArray[2])
    mem1y = float(dataArray[3])
    mem1z = float(dataArray[4])
    #
    mem2x = float(dataArray[5])
    mem2y = float(dataArray[6])
    mem2z = float(dataArray[7])

    timeHr.append(timehr)
    timeT.append(time)
    mem1xD.append(mem1x)
    mem1yD.append(mem1y)
    mem1zD.append(mem1z)
    #
    mem2xD.append(mem2x)
    mem2yD.append(mem2y)
    mem2zD.append(mem2z)

    df = pd.DataFrame({
                        'timeHr':timeHr,
                        'timeT':timeT,
                        'mem1xD':mem1xD,
                        'mem1yD':mem1yD,
                        'mem1zD':mem1zD,
                        'mem2xD':mem2xD,
                        'mem2yD':mem2yD,
                        'mem2zD':mem2zD,

                         }
         )
    df.to_csv(r'time4.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append new data to your dataframe. Passing `mode='a'` in `pd.Dataframe.to_csv` will allow you to do that.

```
import time 

tStart = str(time.time()).split('.')[0]
fileOut = tStart+'.csv'

while True:
    while (arduinoData.inWaiting()==0):
        pass
    arduinoString = arduinoData.readline().decode("utf-8")

    dataArray = arduinoString.split(",")

    timehr = dataArray[0]
    time = float(dataArray[1])/1000

    mem1x = float(dataArray[2])
    mem1y = float(dataArray[3])
    mem1z = float(dataArray[4])
    #
    mem2x = float(dataArray[5])
    mem2y = float(dataArray[6])
    mem2z = float(dataArray[7])

    timeHr.append(timehr)
    timeT.append(time)
    mem1xD.append(mem1x)
    mem1yD.append(mem1y)
    mem1zD.append(mem1z)
    #
    mem2xD.append(mem2x)
    mem2yD.append(mem2y)
    mem2zD.append(mem2z)

    df = pd.DataFrame({
                        'timeHr':timeHr,
                        'timeT':timeT,
                        'mem1xD':mem1xD,
                        'mem1yD':mem1yD,
                        'mem1zD':mem1zD,
                        'mem2xD':mem2xD,
                        'mem2yD':mem2yD,
                        'mem2zD':mem2zD,

                         }
         )
    df.to_csv(fileOut,mode='a', header=False)
```

Comment: @KEVEER Somewhat it did. But now it keeps appending previous list to a new list, making the csv file extremely large after few seconds. I couldn't attach the file to see. But the general idea about not loosing the data is fine.

Comment: @ManuelCalavera I've edited the code to create a new file each time the code is run using the epoch time in seconds as the file name. This should avoid the problem of the csv files getting too big. Additionally, you can try reducing the sample rate your sensor.

Comment: Thank you. A lot. The code is running but now I am having problem locating the file. I think I have messed something. Yes, sampling rate would reduce the amount of data, but for one period of time I need a data point every millisecond.

Comment: Found it. It is a little bit smaller, but it keeps appending new readings to the old ones, not over the old ones. I think the problem is somewhere inside "while" loop.